# How can I ignore SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER for an internal corporate site in Firefox

Tags: firefox, certificate, https

I am getting SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER in Firefox 71 when I try to visit an internal corporate website that I know is secure. This didn't used to happen and works on Chrome and Safari. How can I resolve this?

Comment: I am interesting about different formulation of the problem: Is there any another browser (not FF and not Chrome) which allows completely ignore it and pass? I would be happy to know which one is it. In my case I tested different browsers and for the website which I tried it failed everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to about:config in Firefox, accept the warning about changing advanced settings and set security.enterprise_roots.enabled to true.

Comment: This did not work for me.

Comment: this only works if there IS a valid cert in your windows which an be used instead